# Is it better to use a bunch of view models/data templates to wrap generic types, or a large data template selector?

Tags: c#, wpf, xaml, generics, mvvm

Here is the set up, I have 15 sources of data, each one is a list of objects with a sense of selecting an item I called a `ListViewModel{T}` where T is the type of object in the list and the class inherits ViewModelBase.

I'd be fine with setting up a DataTemplate for each of the distinct types, but I have not been able to get XAML to recognize a generic type. So I have come up with two options.

1. Create view models to wrap each generic type, then have DataTemplates for each one. These would look like

   ```
   public class MyObjectViewModel : ListViewModel<MyObject>
   {
   }
   ```

and

```
 <DataTemplate DataType="{x:Type MyObjectViewModel}">
    <MyView/>
 </DataTemplate>
```

I'd have to create 15 of them.

The other idea was

2. Have a `DataTemplateSelector` control, which would look like

   ```
   public class TabTemplateSelector : DataTemplateSelector
   {
       public DataTemplate MyObjectDataTemplate { get; set; } // 15 of these

       public override DataTemplate SelectTemplate(object item, DependencyObject container)
       {
           DataTemplate dataTemplate = base.SelectTemplate(item, container);

           if (item is ListViewModel<MyObject>)
           {
               dataTemplate = this.MyObjectDataTemplate ;
           } // I'd probably use a case statement on typeof(item)

           return dataTemplate;
       }
   }
   ```

And on the front end

```
<TabTemplateSelector>
        <TabTemplateSelector.MyObjectDataTemplate >
            <DataTemplate DataType="{x:Type MyObjectViewModel}">
                <MyView/>
            </DataTemplate>
        </TabTemplateSelector.MyObjectDataTemplate> // One for each template
</TabTemplateSelector>
```

I am leaning towards the second option because I feel like 15 almost empty classes is a bit of an eye sore, but I'd like to be able to back up my decision and would like to hear about possible alternatives.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

> but I have not been able to get XAML to recognize a generic type.

You're right, it can't :(.

> So I have come up with two options

These are the only two options you have basically. There is not much else to it than what you already discovered I am afraid.

Whether you prefer to define a `DataTemplate` per "wrapper" type or use a `DataTemplateSelector` is a matter of personal flavour really. There is no right and wrong.

But your approach - whichever you choose - is the correct one.